# How to call setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs from WebSettings in nativescript?

Tags: xmlhttprequest, cors, nativescript

In Android native development, to allow **XMLHttpRequests** in some scenarios when we need to request javascript files from an **webview**, one way to do that is setting *setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true)* on WebSettings instance (on API Level 17+).
Is there a way to do that on nativescript?

The error displayed is:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///data/data/.... Cross origin
>   requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, https.",
>   source:
>   file:///data/data/com.yourdomain.appname/files/app/app/frameworks/nativescript.framework/app/components/login/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just quickly looking at the Android docs you could get the WebSettings for the webview with: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#getSettings()

So in the `loaded` event for your webview instance, attach an event handler and in that JS code do something like this:

`function webViewLoaded(args) {
     if (args.object.android) {
      var webView = args.object.android;
      webView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
     } 
}`

Comment: Simple note to help who see this question:
The javascript file will reside on your disk at `..\platforms\android\build\intermediates\assets\F0\debug\app\app\frameworks\nativescript.framework\app\components\login\...`

...and should be referenced on your nativescript component wich contains the web view using relative path as: `../../../../../frameworks/nativescript.framework/app/components/login/my-file.js`